# Tsunami tool for migation ? 

Tags: 2007, 2003, migration

Does anyone have idea about the tsunami tool used fr migration of 2003 to 2007 ? 
please share me links which help me in understanding this tool ? 
Also wat all challenges i have to face when u migrate frm 2003 to 2007 . . 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find details on their website, and probably a trial copy as well.  I did some tests with it 3+ years ago, but chose a different product for the migration I was working on.

The challenges depend on what your goals are and what kind of content you have.  Bringing over sites, documents, list items, etc are possible.  With the big migration I did, I started with a completely clean site build out, and then wanted to migrate content that I mapped to those sites.

I think it is important to be able to configure a job and run it at a later time.  I also think it is important to have control over if the permissions carry over.